# Open existing source in IntelliJ GUI Builder

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, intellij-13

How can I open existing java swing source code and edit it in the **IntelliJ GUI** builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IntelliJ UI Designer does not support editing source code directly; it only supports editing form files. To create a form file for an existing Swing component, you can run your application and have IntelliJ save a part of its UI as a .form file, as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-opening-forms.html) under "Creating snapshots".

Comment: Thank you! That certainly is a step in the right direction. However, even after doing so there still are no components in the form generated? I'm assuming there should be. :)

Comment: It was created in Eclipse with WindowBuilder.

Comment: I mean, which [Swing layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) does your code use?

Comment: Of course, I'm sorry. I know that it's bad practice etc. but it uses an Absolute Layout. It was created by one of my classmates. Do you think it would work better if I remade it with another layout?

Comment: Unfortunately the IntelliJ UI designer does not support AbsoluteLayout and will not recognize components on forms that use it.

Comment: That explains it. Thank you.

Comment: Have you found any solutions?